# How to open the .c file which contains the implementation for any system call in Linux?

Tags: linux, system-calls, runtimemodification

My motive is to open the definition i.e the (`.c`) file of the `shm.h` header, but after following tons of advices and experiencing a lot, I still couldn't not get the exact location of it in Linux. When I open the header files, it says something like the definition of it is defined in XP4.2 but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/lizf/linux-3.4.y.git/tree/ipc/shm.c

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the relevant link Sir. I am studying the file and will let you know about the update. Thanking you again.

Comment: I have studied the file Sir, but according to the link or path mentioned in the code, I followed that and tried to access this file inside the Linux OS (Ubuntu). I mentioned to go inside /root and explore these files but I could not find any such file there and when I searched shm.c in the root, It brings nothing. SO SIR CAN YOU PLEASE LET ME KNOW THE PATH OF THIS FILE INSIDE LINUX OS.

Comment: Unless you have installed the source code on your box, it probably isn't there.  Look in /usr/src.  If there's nothing there, try `sudo aptitude install linux-source` and look again.